# Do KML files have to be on the same domain as the openlayers map?

Tags: kml, openlayers-3

I'm fairly new to openlayers and I'm trying to simply get a kml to show up on an openlayers map.  I have the map and basemap rendering properly in a jsfiddle, after copying out the HTML and javascript from [this example here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/kml.html).

I am trying to load a kml that I have hosted on my own domain.  [The link to it is here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/kml.html).  It is just a subset of some water wells data in Alberta, Canada.  The code I am using to access the data is:

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'http://www.cdnpolimap.com/alberta_wells.kml',
    format: new ol.format.KML()
  })
});
```

However when I look at other people's maps (mostly in other stackoverflow question), I notice that they are all accessing it without all the http://www......" stuff before it.  Am I correct in assuming that the javascript file must be saved on the same domain as the kml and then access it using a relative path? And so therefore I can't access the data when writing in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I hosted everything on a single domain and I can now confirm that yes, the kml resource has to exist on the same domain as the js script.